# string concat two variables and populated another variable and check if the 3rd variables value is available in a fourth variable array and display

Tags: javascript, html, forms

this is the function which is used to combine text and get value. 
 string concat two variables and populated another variable and check if the 3rd variables value is available in a fourth variable array and display

```js
function myFunction() {
  var price = {
    audi: 200,
    bmw: 300,
    volvo: 500
  };
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("mySelect2").value;
  var p = {
    LondonColombo: 100,
    ColomboLondon: 250
  };
  var z = x + y
  var txt = "";
  if (z in p) {
    txt = price[z]
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").value = z;
  document.getElementById("cost").value = txt;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="audi">audi</option>
    <option value="bmw"> bmw </option>
    <option value="volvo">volvo </option>
    <option value="London">London </option>


  </select>

  <select id="mySelect2" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="audi">audi</option>
    <option value="bmw"> bmw </option>
    <option value="volvo">volvo </option>
    <option value="Colombo">Colombo </option>


    <input id="demo">
    <input id="cost">
```

Comment: i need the value in the 4th variable array and display

Comment: `if (z in p ){` you are overwriting the variable value

Comment: var z = x + y ;  are you trying to add two brands?

Comment: @ShaileshRathod check the code snippet and select london colombo the value is undefined how can i get the value ?

Comment: @MonicaAcha yes, its like when you select from a form these 2 brands should combine and give a value

Comment: if i am not wrong, you would select audi and bmw, it should add 200+300. Is it?

Comment: yes, but i need 2 brands concat together in a hidden input so user cannot see. but the value should be displayed

Answer (score -1):

You are seeing undefined because in `txt = price[z]`, price is not defined. Instead of this use `p[z]`

```js
function myFunction() {
  var price = {
    audi: 200,
    bmw: 300,
    volvo: 500
  };
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;

  var y = document.getElementById("mySelect2").value;

  var p = {
    LondonColombo: 100,
    ColomboLondon: 250
  };
  var z = x + y


  var txt = "";
  if (z in p) {

    txt = p[z]

  }
  document.getElementById("demo").value = z;
  document.getElementById("cost").value = txt;

}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="audi">audi</option>
  <option value="bmw"> bmw </option>
  <option value="volvo">volvo </option>
  <option value="London">London </option>


</select>

<select id="mySelect2" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="audi">audi</option>
  <option value="bmw"> bmw </option>
  <option value="volvo">volvo </option>
  <option value="Colombo">Colombo </option>
</select>

<input id="demo">
<input id="cost">
```

Comment: thanks also i want this form to be trigger in the outlook email template any suggestions